# Is octopus halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food

I am in China doing my studies. Anyone tell me Octopus is halal or haram. Because in some Muslim Canteen it is available and some Muslim like to eat it.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer specific to a certain madhab (Shafi, Maliki etc) or a generic answer?

Answer (score 3):

Only **Hanafi Maddhab** says **octopus** is haram because it's not a fish but the rest of the Maddhabs (**Shafi'i, hanbali, Maliki etc**) give permission, since they consider any creature from the sea as halal so you can eat it if you don't follow the Hanafi opinion on this.
Mussels, squid and octopus do not have all the **features of fish**; therefore they will not be regarded as fish. Hence, it is not permissible to eat mussels, squid and octopus in the **Hanafī school of jurisprudence**. ⚖ 
More details are given in this [URL](https://darulfiqh.com/knowledgebase/is-it-permissible-to-eat-prawns-mussels-squid-and-octopus)